# Why does inline-block which equal 100% not fit on one line

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3GPTy/4/

CSS:

```
.price {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-right: 8%;
}
.last {
    margin-right: 0%
}

 .container {
    width: 780px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

What I don't understand is, I have **4*19 + 3*8** which should equal 100% but still it doesn't fit on one line?

Comment: I need a bit more than that to get my teeth into im afraid

Comment: Spaces. They take up space. Between your `inline-block` elements, you have spaces. So your total width is `4*19 + 3*8 + some extra for spaces > 100%`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is right. There are several ways to get around here. You could just use float instead or negative margins.

Comment: or comment out the white space between elements - inline block means they are treat like words in a sentence - if you have space between the words it will appear

Comment: When I apply ```font-size: 0;``` to my price class my boxes go completely

Comment: I'd rather not use negative margins. A solution with float or font-size is fine though

Comment: @Jimmy You are right. Floating is a much better option. I'd prefer that. Font-size seems ok too. I think they are both better than negative margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.price {
   width: 19%;
   background-color: pink;
   margin-right: 8%;
   float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3GPTy/10/

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate further, here's a few ways of solving the problem:

- Comment out the space

  ```
  </div><!--
  --><div>
  ```
- Put the space in the tags

  ```
  </div
  ><div>
  ```
- Just shove it on one line

  ```
  </div><div>
  ```

The last one especially, ideally you should be minifying your HTML - I do on-the-fly with PHP magic, and with that I can write readable HTML *and* not have spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I do prefer the float option

Comment: @Jimmy All right, but keep in mind that using `float` comes with its own set of problems ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Float is a much better solution than the first two solutions here. Imagine some other developer maintaining your code would just remove the 'unnecessary comments' in a few places. He/She would be baffled to see a change in the layout and might spend hours searching what happened when they 'really didn't make a code change'.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol There's no denying that these 'fixes' work. The thing is I'd only use or recommend them in case I've run out of all other possible solutions!!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the how the browser treats fonts; between letters it puts a small sliver of whitespace to space the characters out correctly. Counterintuitively this idea is applied to all elements, so if you have two div's at 50% width they will not fit on the same line because the small white space added makes the total width greater than 100%.

To solve this add:

```
font-size: 0;
```

to the parent div. You can then set the desired font size in its children to remove the white spacing that would have otherwise been added

Here's more detail on the issue from this CSS Tricks [article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), as well as other soultions including floating the elements and using comments.